# How to make a dictionary with lists instead of a float object

Tags: python, list, dictionary

This is my code:

```py
def infty(graph):
  return 1 + sum([e[1] for lst in graph.values() for e in lst]) / 2
print(infty({"A" : [["B", 10], ["D", 5]], "B" : [["A", 10], ["C", 5]], "C" : [["B", 5], ["D", 15]], "D" : [["C", 15], ["A", 5]]}))


def initial(graph,source):
  distances = {}

  for vertex in graph:
    distances[vertex] = infty(graph)

  distances[source] = 0
  return distances
```

The output should be:
`{"A":[0], "B":[36], "C":[36], "D":[36]}`

but my output is:
`{'A': 0, 'B': 36.0, 'C': 36.0, 'D': 36.0}`

Comment: Did you mean: `distances[vertex] = [int(infty(graph))]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `initial` function returns a `float` while you want an array containing the `float` (or int?). You can change your function to:

```py
def initial(graph,source):
  distances = {}

  for vertex in graph:
    distances[vertex] = [infty(graph)]

  distances[source] = 0
  return distances
```

You can additionally add a conversion to `int`if desired.

---

#### Additional notes

You can simplify this function by using a dictionary comprehension:

```py
def initial(graph, source):
  return {k: [infty(graph)] for k in graph} | {source: [0]}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Did not look into the function and its working to convert float to list just put [int(return value)] **

def infty(graph):
return [int(1 + sum([e[1] for lst in graph.values() for e in lst]) / 2)]
print(infty({"A" : [["B", 10], ["D", 5]], "B" : [["A", 10], ["C", 5]], "C" : [["B", 5], ["D", 15]], "D" : [["C", 15], ["A", 5]]}))

def initial(graph,source):
distances = {}

for vertex in graph:
distances[vertex] = infty(graph)

distances[source] = 0
return distances